# Using QueryPerformanceCounter in c sharp but not getting precise results

Tags: c#

I am using QueryPerformanceCounter to get the precise timing behaviour in my c sharp program. But if i measure the timing using thread.sleep it is not giving excpected results.
I followed standard example given at msdn site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650674.aspx

```
    myTimer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        // Method to time
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    myTimer.Stop();
```

Results are :

Iterations: 5
Average time per iteration:
0.208957983452184 seconds

Datetime.Now gives :

Duration of test run:
5 seconds
5000 milliseconds

Can you please suggest what could be possible error?

Comment: I would check the math under the `QueryPerfCounter.Duration` because their sample outputs correctly for me or make sure that the seconds line under the iterations is `1000000000`.

Comment: Can you show more code - the one that outputs numbers you show? (I hope you are using StopWatch class instead of writing you own...)

Comment: I tried the same code given in link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650674.aspx . One interesting thing is that its not working on my machine which has Intel Core 2 Duo proocessor 2.99 GHz, but it works nicely on another machine which is having intel Xeon 2 GHz

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with code... Try to rewrite using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch (uses the same infrastrucure as the samepl) and see if you get the same strange results. It may be worth to re-title question to reflect environment where is fails so other people try to answer.